# JclCompression, how to abort or stop

Tags: delphi

Does any one know how to stop/abort compression or decompression while working with JclCompression?

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement a progress handler and attach it to the compression class through the `OnProgress` event handler. Then, in your progress handler, set `CancelCurrentOperation` to `True`. The first parameter passed to the progress handler is the `TJclCompressionArchive` instance.

Your handler might look like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.CompressionArchiveProgress(Sender: TObject; 
    const Value, MaxValue: Int64);
begin
  if FAborted then
    (Sender as TJclCompressionArchive).CancelCurrentOperation := True;
end;
```

I have assumed that you are using one of the descendents of `TJclCompressionArchive`.

---

The JEDI code is supplied as source and so you can inspect the source code yourself to work out details such as this.

Comment: David 
Thank you very much.
that is exactly what I was looking for